# clip-path com problemas no Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Estou utilizando a técnica de clip-path para fazer um polígono em determinada área do site:

```
.cliped {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 75%);
    -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 75%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 75%);
    clip-path: url("#polygon");
}
```

Porém dessa forma não funciona no Firefox. Com uma pesquisa rápida descobri que o Firefox precisa de uma adição (web standards my ***) de SVG:

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clippath id="polygon">
                        <polygon points="0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 0.75"></polygon>
        </clippath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

E como vocês podem ver [aqui](http://drop.studiogt.com.br/cadiz/index.php/imoveis-interna) não resolveu bulhufas.

Alguém ai se habilita?

Comment: Mas pra qual elmento está sendo apontado o `.cliped`?

Comment: ClipPath é uma funcionalidade experimental. [Nenhum navegador dá suporte completo ainda](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). Então você mesmo colocou "your *** " na reta. :)

Comment: <img class="cliped" src="img/banner-imoveis.jpg" alt="" title="" />

Comment: Pelo que vi ele dá suporte á todos os navegadores exceto os IE's da vida. Mas não preciso dar suporte pro IE.